# Trying to relate tags to products by product category

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Ok here's is what I am trying to do. I have a **tags** column `(pid,tag)` and a **products** column `(id, name)`. There are a ton of tags related to one product.

I have a **tags filter** option where I can select an tags and it will filter the products by tags. There can be 1 tag being queried or 10 tags being queried. For instance, there are check boxes with all the tags and the user can select as many tags as they want and it should filter the products that have those tags associated.

Can't seem to figure out the fastest way to do this.

I can get each products tags pretty quick, but how would I get each product with the tags by tags. Here is what I am expecting.

Tags being searched by: 'Deck Mount, Single, 3in'

**products**

id, name, array(Deck Mount, Single, 3in, Strait, Black, Green, Blue)

```
select p.* 
from products p 
HAVING p.loc_cat = 'Faucets' 
AND (select pid 
     from tags 
     where pid = p.id 
     AND tag = 'BODY:DECK MOUNT');
```

That's an example of the query I am using. Here is are the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23128 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `prod_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` text,
  `harmonize` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `loc_cat` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `loc_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `pcode` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcodedesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `pid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_string` text,
  `upc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date__updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prod_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3908 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With many tags in the tags column related to one product. I am using ajax to search for a set of tags to grab the product ids to get the products. The problem is there are SO MANY, so it takes forever. I think I'm over thinking it.

Every time I check a check box I run the query and send a comma separated string of all the selected checkboxes.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: You will need to build or use a database class which allows you to build the query based on what's necessary. I.e. $query->addWhere("tag.name = 'Deck Mount'")->addWhere("tag.name = '3in'"); Otherwise it's just a matter of proper execution of joins. If you come back with what you've tried so far I'll help further.

Comment: Are jquery, ajax and codeigniter relevant for this question? What have you done so far? It's not really clear what you're trying to do (you could use an `AND` in your query, perhaps?), post the code you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out guys. Here is my query now.

```
select p.*, 
   (select GROUP_CONCAT(tag) from tags where pid = p.id) as tags 
   from products p 
   HAVING p.loc_cat = 'Pre-rinse Units' 
   AND tags LIKE '%BODY:DECK MOUNT%' AND tags LIKE '%BODY:SINGLE%';
```